# Why scrollView scrolls down when other textField becomes active?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have two UITextFields in the scrollView. Because of keyboard, I want that touching on each textField will scroll the scrollView  up (together with 2 textFields in it) and the touched field will be at the top of the screen.
My textFieldDidBeginEditing function looks so:

```
- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
      CGPoint point = CGPointMake( 0 , textField.center.y - 25  );
    [self setContentOffset:point animated:YES];
}
```

The problem when during editing of one textField and I am touching the other textField - than the scrollView scrolls down to (0,0) position. Why does it happen? I don't have "setContentOffset" in any other code except in textFieldDidBeginEditing function. How can I fix it so that touch to other textField will scroll the scrollView up?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 216, 0.0);
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, textFieds.frame.origin.y + kOtherViewsHeightWhichMightNotBeInSameViewAsScrollView, 10, 10);

    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame] animated:YES];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
    return YES;
}
```

Don't forget to set your view controller as the delegate of your text fields

Answer (score 0):

When working with multiple UITextFields it is helpful to declare an activeTextField property and assign it didBegin and didEnd delegate calls

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) activeTextField;

-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
  {
   self.activeTextField = textField;
  }  
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
  {
    self.activeTextField = nil;
  }
```

Then to adjust scrollView to the UITextField

Add This observer in viewDidLoad

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                     selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                         name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                       object:nil];
```

Implement this method

```
#define paddingAboveTextField 20
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
  UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize.height, 0.0);
  scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
  scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
  CGRect rectMinusKeyboard = self.view.frame;
  rectMinusKeyboard.size.height -= keyboardSize.height;
 if (!CGRectContainsPoint(rectMinusKeyboard, self.activeTextField.frame.origin) ) {
    CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, self.activeTextField.frame.origin.y - (keyboardSize.height-paddingAboveTextField)); 
    [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
  }
}
```